# Calling on css that hides within a figcaption

Tags: css, html

I am currently using the "hera" design featured [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/index2.html) however the original code uses presumably [Font Awesome](https://fonticons.com/?utm_source=font_awesome_homepage&utm_medium=display&utm_content=ad_4_more_icons&utm_campaign=promo_4.3_update), I'd like to replace these icons with my own text or possibly images. The code I'm working with is as follows:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <figure class="effect-hera">
    <img src="img/17.jpg" alt="img17" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Tittle <span>Tittle two</span></h2>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-image-o"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-image-o"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-archive-o"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-code-o"></i></a>
      </p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

I added a `<p>` tag to replace the `<i>` tag however it didn't hide the span like in the demo; I presumed its due to my misunderstanding of the `<figcaption>` tag however after research I'm not sure. In even his CSS files I couldnt find the class linked to the middle `<i>` tags so Im stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<i>`'s have `opacity:0` until `<figure class="effect-hera">` is hovered over, so if you want the same effect keep the `<i>`'s. If you want to stop Font Awesome, remove all the CSS classes in the `<i>`'s and use a different class for your own images/fonts. I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/00k6zrdg/) of my working code, it is also below:

```
<div class="grid">
  <figure class="effect-hera">
    <img src="img/17.jpg" alt="img17" />
    <figcaption>
      <h2>Tittle <span>Tittle two</span></h2>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-fw"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-fw"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-fw"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-fw"></i></a>
      </p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-fw {
background:url(http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png) no-repeat left top;
width:32px;
height:32px;
display:inline-block;
background-size:100%;
float:left;
}

.grid {
width:64px;
display:block;
}
```

Comment: hey sorry just got internet back and saw this, much appreciated. Out of curiosity in both your example and my re creating for it the icons don't fall into the same 4x4 block but instead a line; how would I recreate this and why isn't it the same if all we did was replace the images? Thank again

Comment: yikes, I completely forgot about this. Looks like you should leave the `.fa-fw` class in the `<i>`'s... I'll update my answer in a second.